# Can two websites be mapped to same folder with different default file

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a website www.example.com and I want to have a subdomain www.subdomain.example.com.

What I want to achieve is this

1- www.example.com opens the `index.aspx` file in the root folder
2- example.com opens the `index.aspx` file in the root folder
3- www.subdomain.example.com should open `someFile.aspx` in the main website
4- subdomain.example.com should open `someFile.aspx` in the main website

I have tried to do this.
I have uploaded the website to my host and the site is accessible through with and without www, so the first 2 are achieved.

Now for the subdomain part, I have created another website on my host and mapped it to the same root folder as the main website. I have tried to setup the default file in the subdomain settings to be `someFile.aspx` but it does not open that file, rather it opens `index.aspx` file when I enter subdomain.example.com with or without www prefix in the browser.

What is the best way to do it.